# Add Newly Created Excel Workbook onto Outlook Directly

Tags: excel, vba

My code consists of two parts.
First is to copy data from database onto newly created workbook.
Second is to attach and send newly created workbook via outlook to someone.
First part is was completed successfully.
But I couldn't fix the second part.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheetToAnotherWorkbook()

Dim wbk1 As Workbook:           Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wbk2 As Workbook
Dim Report As Worksheet:        Set Report = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Dim CopySht As Worksheet

With Report
.Cells.Copy
End With

Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Add
Set CopySht = wbk2.Sheets("Sheet1")

With Cells
.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
End With

ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80

End Sub


Sub AddFileToMail()

Dim OutLookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim sourcefile As String


Set OutLookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set myMail = OutLookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

ThisWorkbook.Save
sourcefile = ThisWorkbook.FullName

myMail.Attachments.Add sourcefile


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe Something Like:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheetToAnotherWorkbook()

Dim wbk1 As Workbook:           Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wbk2 As Workbook
Dim Report As Worksheet:        Set Report = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Dim CopySht As Worksheet

With Report
.Cells.Copy
End With

Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Add
wbk2.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "workbooktosend.xlsx"
Set CopySht = wbk2.Sheets("Sheet1")

With Cells
.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
End With

ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80

End Sub


Sub AddFileToMail()

Dim OutLookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim sourcefile As String


Set OutLookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set myMail = OutLookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


myMail.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "workbooktosend.xlsx"


End Sub
```

First you save that File in the Fisrt Subject and in the Second you can add it using the PAth.